# ${\mathrm{GL}}(4,{\mathbb{F}}_q)$ action on the $(2,4)$-Grassmann

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, group-actions, grassmannian

Let ${\mathbb{F}}_q$ be the finite field of order $q$ and ${\mathcal{G}}(2,4)$ denote the set of all $2$-dimensional subspaces of ${\mathbb{F}}^4_q$. Let $P$ denote the $(2,2)$-parabolic (which is the subgroup of all matrices of ${\mathrm{GL}}(4,{\mathbb{F}}_q)$ which has lower triangular $2 \times 2$ block zero while written in $2 \times 2$ sub-blocks).

There is a natural transitive left action of ${\mathrm{GL}}(4,{\mathbb{F}}_q)$ on ${\mathcal{G}}(2,4)$: if $W \in {\mathcal{G}}(2,4), g \in {\mathrm{GL}}(4,{\mathbb{F}}_q)$ with $W = {\mathrm{span}} \{ v_1, v_2 \}$, then $g \cdot W := {\mathrm{span}} \{ g \cdot v_1, g \cdot v_2 \}$. Setting $\{ e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4 \}$ as the canonical basis of ${\mathbb{F}}^4_q$, clearly $P$ turns out to be the stabiliser of $W_0 = {\mathrm{span}} \{ e_1, e_2 \}$.

${\mathrm{\bf Question.1:}}$ Show that ${\mathrm{GL}}(4,{\mathbb{F}}_q)/P$ can be identified with ${\mathcal{G}}(2,4)$.

Since $P$ is not a normal subgroup ${\mathrm{GL}}(4,{\mathbb{F}}_q)$, this identification doesn't seems to come from the natural action. What is the best way to see this?

${\mathrm{\bf Question.2:}}$ Under this identification, two elements of ${\mathrm{GL}}(4,{\mathbb{F}}_q)/P$ are in the same orbit of $P$ if and only if the corresponding subspaces intersect in the same dimensional subspaces of ${\mathrm{span}} \{ e_1, e_2 \}$.

What is the meaning of orbit here?

One can make an equivalence relation on ${\mathcal{G}}(2,4)$ satisfying this property to explain the orbit. However, I don't see a natural connection with ${\mathrm{GL}}(4,{\mathbb{F}}_q)/P$. What am I missing?

Comment: Why does $P$ not being normal matter?

Comment: Most sources explaining group actions ought to define the term "orbit" right about the same time they define the term "stabilizer," so it's strange to read someone asking what the term orbit means while also using the term stabilizer...

Comment: The word "orbit" is loosely used in combinatorics for equivalence classes, as most of them come from permutation action of some sort, whereas stabiliser here is very precise. Not sure about this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ acts on a set $\Omega$, the action is called **transitive** if for every $\omega,\omega'\in\Omega$ there exists a $g\in G$ for which $\omega'=g\omega$. The **stabilizer** $\mathrm{Stab}(\omega)\le G$ of a point $\omega\in G$ is the set of all $g\in G$ which fix $\omega$, i.e. $g\omega=\omega$. The **orbit** $\mathrm{Orb}(\omega)$ of a point $\omega\in\Omega$ is the set of all "translates" $g\omega$ of $\omega$ (for all $g\in G$). Note a $G$-set $\Omega$ is transitive if and only if $\Omega=\mathrm{Orb}(\omega)$ for any (or all) $\omega\in\Omega$, i.e. it's all one orbit. Two $G$-sets $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are called **equivalent** or **isomorphic** if there is a $G$-equivariant bijection between them. A coset space $G/H$ is itself a $G$-set, with the action by left-multiplication.

The **orbit-stabilizer theorem** says if $G\curvearrowright\Omega$ is a transitive action then $\Omega$ is equivalent (as a $G$-set) to a coset space $G/\mathrm{Stab}(\omega)$ (for any point $\omega\in\Omega$). Specifically, $g\mathrm{Stab}(\omega)\leftrightarrow g\omega$. Note $\mathrm{Stab}(g\omega)=g\mathrm{Stab}(\omega)g^{-1}$ so this sets up a one-to-one correspondence between isomorphism classes of transitive $G$-sets and conjugacy classes of subgroups $H$.

In particular, $\mathrm{GL}_4\mathbb{F}_2$ acts on $\mathrm{Gr}_2\mathbb{F}_2^4$ transitively, and the stabilizer of the first-two-coordinates-plane is $P$, so we automatically know that $\mathrm{GL}_4\mathbb{F}_2/P$ is equivalent to $\mathrm{Gr}_2\mathbb{F}_2^4$. This answers (1).

For (2) you'll want to explore how $P$ acts on $\mathrm{Gr}_2\mathbb{F}_2^4$...

Comment: Ah, now I see what my confusion is. The equivariance simply identifies the actions; so both are transitive. I was influenced by (2) to see (1). The action of $P$ then de-"fuse" the orbits into three, didn't see that coming. Thanks.